# Play Framework how to purposely delay a response

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, threadpool

We have a Play app, currently using version 2.6. We are trying to prevent dictionary attacks against our login by delaying a "failed login" message back to our users when they provide a failed password. We currently hash and salt and have all the best practices, but we are not sure if we are delaying correctly. So we have in our Controller:

```
public Result login() { return ok(loginHtml) }
```

and we have a:

```
public Result loginAction()
{ 
  // Check for user in database
  User user = User.find.query()...

  // Was the user found?
  if (user == null) {

     // Wrong password! Delay and redirect
     Thread.sleep(10000);  <<-- how do delay correctly?
     return redirect(routes.Controller.login())
  }

  // User is not null, so all good!
  ...

}
```

We are not sure if `Thread.sleep(10000)` is the best way to delay a response since this might hang other requests that come in, or use too many thread from the default pool. We have noticed that under 80+ hits per second the Play Framework does not route our HTTP calls to the Routes. That is, if we receive a HTTP POST request, our app will not even send that request to the Controller until 20+ seconds later, HOWEVER, in the SAME time period if we get a HTTP GET request, our app will process that GET instantly!

Currently we have 300 threads as the min/max in our Akka settings for the default fork pool. Any insights would be appreciated. We run a t2.xlarge AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.sleep` causes current thread blocking, please, try to avoid using it in production code as much as possible.

What you need to use, is `CompletionStage` / `CompletableFuture` or any abstraction for deeling with async programming and asynchronous action.

Please, take a look for more details about asynchronios actions: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaAsync

In your case solution would look like something too (excuse me, please, this might have mistakes - I'm Scala engineer primary):

```
import play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecutionContext;
import play.mvc.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class LoginController extends Controller {

  private HttpExecutionContext httpExecutionContext;

  // Create and inject separate ScheduledExecutorService
  private ScheduledExecutorService executor; 

  @Inject
  public LoginController(HttpExecutionContext ec,
                         ScheduledExecutorService executor) {
    this.httpExecutionContext = ec;
    this.executor = executor;
  }

  public CompletionStage<Result> loginAction() {
    User user = User.find.query()...
    if (user == null) {
        return executor.schedule(() -> {redirect(routes.Controller.login());}, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } else {
      // return another response
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, amazing! Thanks Ivan -- you're a life saver! This is the ONLY place on the web where such a practical example is shown!

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this approach at all. This hogs threads for no reason and can probably cause your entire system to lock up if someone finds out you are doing this and they have malicious ideas. Let me propose a better approach:

In the `User` table store a nullable `LocalDateTime` of the last login attempt time.

When you fetch the user from the DB check the last attempt time (compare to LocalDateTime.now()), if 10 secs have passed since last attempt perform the password comparison.

If passwords don't match store the last attempt time as now.

This can also be handled gracefully on the front end if you provide good error responses.

EDIT: If you want to delay login attempts NOT based on the user, you could create an attempt table and store last attempt by IP address.

If you really want to do your way which I don't recommend you need to read up on this first: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ThreadPools

Comment: That's a great idea about the time delay check -- makes sense. Let's just suppose the challenge is to delay the controller's response by 10 seconds. I've read all I could find about threadpools. Would the controller respond a future, and that future would have an infinite loop that stops after 10 seconds have passed? There is no reference implementation for a 10 second delay that does not spike the cpu.

Comment: Well then you probably want to use a custom dispatcher and only do the delays on it. Similar to how they do here https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/2.8.x/play-java-ebean-example/app/repository/ComputerRepository.java#L49 Notice how the provide an execution context for the DB operations. Again I would strongly advise against using this pattern tho.

Answer (score 0):

A delayed response indeed punishes a legitimate user who accidentally gives an incorrect password, and I don't think it is a good application design. I am doing something similar in my project, where I keep track of the fail count for the ID and disable the ID if the max attempt exceeded. On system-wise, we blacklist the IPs that look suspicious.